# Add a download button in the new window

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a download button in the new window, that should download a contents. Below is the sample html code for that. Can anyone help me? I have added a download button. But not sure how to add script and where to add it?

```
<table border=1>
<tr> 
<th>  </th> 
<th> sub_domain </th> 
<th> nReviews </th> 
<th> Ratings_e </th> 
<th> Text_e </th> 
<th> rn </th> 
<th> launcher_html </th>  
</tr>  

<tr> 
<td align=\"right\"> 1 </td> 
<td> a1 </td> <td align=\"right\">   2 </td> 
<td> 1, 2 </td> 
<td> asd, dfdsf </td> 

<td align="left">   1 </td> 
<td> <script>    function openWindow1() {     var newtab1 = window.open("", "anotherWindow", "width=300,height=150");     newtab1.document.open();    newtab1.document.write("<table border=1><button onclick='exportTableToCSV('members.csv')'>Export HTML Table To CSV File</button><br></br><tr><th>Ratings_e</th><th>Text_e</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>asd</td></tr><tr><td> 2</td><td> dfdsf</td></tr></table>");    } </script>  



<button onclick="openWindow1()"> Open Window </button>   
</td> </tr>\n   </table>
```

Comment: where is anything resembling download functionality? Please go through the guide and ask the question again - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The short answer is to create a button that  creates a Blob object from the CSV text using `new Blob()` , a url for the blob using `URL.createObjectURL()`, a download link element for the url, and then clicks the link to start the download before calling `URL.revokeObjectURL()` to make the blob available for garbage collection from memory.  Please delete comments leading up to this.

Comment: Thanks I have tried to get the answer. But still I have one thing pending. I have posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68078431/download-the-contents-in-the-pop-up-window

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not opening up a url in your `window.open()`.  If you have a download URL for the files, then you can do this:

```js
var newtab2 = window.open("<download link>", "anotherWindow", "width=300, height=150");
```

If you don't have a download link, then perhaps what you could do is upload it to a [GitHub](https://github.com) repository and get a download link from there.