# Download the contents in the pop up window

Tags: javascript, html

Below is the html code that has a pop up window when you click on "open window". I have added the download button (inside this). Once the user clicks on it, The table should be downloaded. I am missing something here. Can anyone help me?

I am almost in the final stage. Only thing pending is to have the contents downloaded

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>  </th>
<th> sub_domain </th>
<th> nReviews </th>
<th> Ratings_e </th>
<th> Text_e </th>
<th> rn </th>
<th> launcher_html </th>  
</tr>  

<tr>
<td align=\"right\"> 1 </td>
<td> a1 </td> <td align=\"right\">   2 </td>
<td> 1, 2 </td>
<td> asd, dfdsf </td>

<td align="left">   1 </td>
<td> <script>  

function openWindow1() {     var newtab1 = window.open("", "anotherWindow", "width=300,height=150");  
  newtab1.document.open();  
 
 
  newtab1.document.write('<table border=1> <button onclick="window.opener.exportTableToCSV(\'members.csv\');">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button><br></br><tr><th>Ratings_e</th><th>Text_e</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>asd</td></tr><tr><td> 2</td><td> dfdsf</td></tr></table>');   
 function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
alert("I am an alert box!");
    var csv = [];
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");
   
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");
       
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
            row.push(cols[j].innerText);
       
        csv.push(row.join(","));        
    }

    // Download CSV file
    alert('Hey')
    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
}

  function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
    var csvFile;
    var downloadLink;

    // CSV file
    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

    // Download link
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    // File name
    downloadLink.download = filename;

    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

    // Hide download link
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

    // Add the link to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    // Click download link
    downloadLink.click();
}
 
  }


  </script>  



<button onclick="openWindow1()"> Open Window </button>  
</td> </tr>   </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user11740857

Your code already works, except from one silly mistake, that is that you misplaced the closing } of "openWindow1" function.

As you placed it after "downloadCSV" function, it means that "exportTableToCSV" and "downloadCSV" are in the scope of the function "openWindow1" and won't be defined in the parent window itself, so you can't use "window.opener" to acces that functions.

Solution 1: (and probably the best one)

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th> sub_domain</th>
        <th> nReviews</th>
        <th> Ratings_e</th>
        <th> Text_e</th>
        <th> rn</th>
        <th> launcher_html</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align=\"right\"> 1</td>
        <td> a1</td>
        <td align=\"right\"> 2</td>
        <td> 1, 2</td>
        <td> asd, dfdsf</td>

        <td align="left"> 1</td>
        <td>
            <script>

                function openWindow1() {
                    var newtab1 = window.open("", "anotherWindow", "width=300,height=150");
                    newtab1.document.open();


                    newtab1.document.write('<table border=1> <button onclick="window.opener.exportTableToCSV(\'members.csv\');">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button><br></br><tr><th>Ratings_e</th><th>Text_e</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>asd</td></tr><tr><td> 2</td><td> dfdsf</td></tr></table>');
                }

                function exportTableToCSV(filename) {
                    alert("I am an alert box!");
                    var csv = [];
                    var rows = document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

                        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
                            row.push(cols[j].innerText);

                        csv.push(row.join(","));
                    }

                    // Download CSV file
                    alert('Hey')
                    downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
                }

                function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
                    var csvFile;
                    var downloadLink;

                    // CSV file
                    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

                    // Download link
                    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

                    // File name
                    downloadLink.download = filename;

                    // Create a link to the file
                    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

                    // Hide download link
                    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

                    // Add the link to DOM
                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

                    // Click download link
                    downloadLink.click();
                }


            </script>


            <button onclick="openWindow1()"> Open Window</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The other option is to define those functions as variables and give them to the opened window. But the code above should work.

Moreover, I'd suggest you to use an IDE that hightlights your code indentation, so you don't get frustrated but this mistakes!

Cheers

**EDITED**

Sorry, I didn't see that it was being exported the content of the parent table. This is a problem with the scopes. You need to define the functions so as to access the scope of the new window. Here you go the code for that, in which you can see that I'm declaring the exporting functions at the new window, and that we are passing the scope window to the first function. This is so you can use that functions in the partent window too.

Check if that meets your need

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th> sub_domain</th>
        <th> nReviews</th>
        <th> Ratings_e</th>
        <th> Text_e</th>
        <th> rn</th>
        <th> launcher_html</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align=\"right\"> 1</td>
        <td> a1</td>
        <td align=\"right\"> 2</td>
        <td> 1, 2</td>
        <td> asd, dfdsf</td>

        <td align="left"> 1</td>
        <td>
            <script>

                function openWindow1() {
                    var newtab1 = window.open("", "anotherWindow", "width=300,height=150");
                    newtab1.document.open();

                    newtab1.document.write('<table border=1> <button onclick="exportTableToCSV(window,\'members.csv\');">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button><br></br><tr><th>Ratings_e</th><th>Text_e</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>asd</td></tr><tr><td> 2</td><td> dfdsf</td></tr></table>');
                    newtab1.exportTableToCSV = exportTableToCSV;
                    newtab1.downloadCSV = downloadCSV;
                }

                function exportTableToCSV(scopedWindow,filename) {
                    alert("I am an alert box!");
                    var csv = [];
                    var rows = scopedWindow.document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

                        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
                            row.push(cols[j].innerText);

                        csv.push(row.join(","));
                    }

                    // Download CSV file
                    alert('Hey')
                    scopedWindow.downloadCSV(csv.join("\n"), filename);
                }

                function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
                    var csvFile;
                    var downloadLink;

                    // CSV file
                    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

                    // Download link
                    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

                    // File name
                    downloadLink.download = filename;

                    // Create a link to the file
                    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

                    // Hide download link
                    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

                    // Add the link to DOM
                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

                    // Click download link
                    downloadLink.click();
                }


            </script>


            <button onclick="openWindow1()"> Open Window</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Cheers x2

Comment: Hi Thanks. but i go this actually. RIght now it is downloading the first table (outside one). But i need to download the table that is there in the pop up window

Comment: Were you able to get my point :) Your code is right if I want to download outside table, But It will not download inside table

Comment: Hi! I've editid the answer to correct that issue, I didn't notice it, sorry. There what we need to do is to give the scope window to the function, so it knows which document to use

Comment: Hi Ruben, I think we can declare functions within script at any place right?. ALso i tried putting another row to the tables (first table). Now the download button is not working. Not sure . Should we declare the ID. I have the code here. Can you help me here please

Comment: Hi! Yes, you can declare the functions at a global scope, and probably they should be, because they're gonna be used globally. In the example you have given as an answer, it seems to work properly, which is the matter?

Comment: No it is not. The downloaded contents are not correct. Can you please try once

Comment: I have tried it, and it's working on my computer, the download button is downloading the table of the new window as a csv. For both rows the data you are passing to that new window is the same, show the result is the same.

The simple answer: you are calling the same function in both buttons, so the result is the same. If you want the second button to use the second function, change the call of that button.

Finally, you can declare both functions at the same <script> tag, because that only affects to load of javascript, but not to javascript scope.

Comment: Yeah i got ur point, Now I have changed it below. Again it is not working. Can you paste your code once:)

Comment: The code I'm testing, which is working, is the same as the one you have updated. And it works properly, have you forced the refresh of the browser so it destroys the cache?

Comment: Very strange. I opened in the new window and tried. Still the same. Not sure why it is deferring.  Did you get a chance to see the csv file? Is it properly downloading ?

Comment: The first CSV is: 
   Ratings_e,Text_e1,asd2,dfdsf   
   The second gives:
   Ratings_e,Text_e2,asd12,dfdsf1

Comment: Yes that is where the issue is. It is not downloading properly as per the table in pop up. You got my points :)

Comment: I think you didn't read it, it's downloading properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234112/discussion-between-user11740857-and-ruben-jorajuria-lazaro).

Answer (score 0):

For 2 rows

```
<script>

                function exportTableToCSV(scopedWindow,filename) {
                    alert("I am an alert box!");
                    var csv = [];
                    var rows = scopedWindow.document.querySelectorAll("table tr");

                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll("td, th");

                        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++)
                            row.push(cols[j].innerText);

                        csv.push(row.join(","));
                    }

                    // Download CSV file
                    alert('Hey')
                    scopedWindow.downloadCSV(csv.join(""), filename);
                }

                function downloadCSV(csv, filename) {
                    var csvFile;
                    var downloadLink;

                    // CSV file
                    csvFile = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/csv"});

                    // Download link
                    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

                    // File name
                    downloadLink.download = filename;

                    // Create a link to the file
                    downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);

                    // Hide download link
                    downloadLink.style.display = "none";

                    // Add the link to DOM
                    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

                    // Click download link
                    downloadLink.click();
                }

</script>


<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th> sub_domain</th>
        <th> nReviews</th>
        <th> Ratings_e</th>
        <th> Text_e</th>
        <th> rn</th>
        <th> launcher_html</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align=\"right\"> 1</td>
        <td> a1</td>
        <td align=\"right\"> 2</td>
        <td> 1, 2</td>
        <td> asd, dfdsf</td>

        <td align="left"> 1</td>
        <td>
            <script>

                function openWindow1() {
                    var newtab1 = window.open("", "anotherWindow", "width=300,height=150");
                    newtab1.document.open();

                    newtab1.document.write('<table border=1> <button onclick="exportTableToCSV(window,\'members.csv\');">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button><br></br><tr><th>Ratings_e</th><th>Text_e</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>asd</td></tr><tr><td> 2</td><td> dfdsf</td></tr></table>');
                    newtab1.exportTableToCSV = exportTableToCSV;
                    newtab1.downloadCSV = downloadCSV;
                }




            </script>


            <button onclick="openWindow1()"> Open Window</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align=\"right\"> 1</td>
        <td> a1</td>
        <td align=\"right\"> 2</td>
        <td> 2, 2</td>
        <td> asd1, dfdsf1</td>

        <td align="left"> 1</td>
        <td>
            <script>

                function openWindow2() {
                    var newtab2 = window.open("", "anotherWindow", "width=300,height=150");
                    newtab2.document.open();

                    newtab2.document.write('<table border=1> <button onclick="exportTableToCSV(window,\'members.csv\');">Export HTML Table To CSV File</button><br></br><tr><th>Ratings_e</th><th>Text_e</th></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>asd1</td></tr><tr><td> 2</td><td> dfdsf1</td></tr></table>');
                    newtab2.exportTableToCSV = exportTableToCSV;
                    newtab2.downloadCSV = downloadCSV;
                }




            </script>


            <button onclick="openWindow2()"> Open Window</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a reason to write two open window functions for multiple rows? Also, in the opened window, the download button is placed as a direct child element of the table element - which is not valid HTML

Comment: You mean to say. 2 open windows are not required. Can you please try to help me here

Comment: The post is primarily about how to allow the user to download data from an opened window. The code posted put the code to open a child window in a data cell. To generalize it you would put the script outside the table (once) and have a button in each row (of the parent table) pass the row that is in to the window open function as an argument. That way the window open function could  generate the child window's table from data in the row whose download button was clicked. My comment was about not hand coding multiple functions that essentially did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Datatables

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.7.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>

    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether what are the requirements for your project. but if you want to download the complete table. I would prefer to use `Jquery Datatables`. The Jquery Datatables has a built-in function to download table in PDF, EXCEL, CSV, also you can print it. you donot need to write such long codes. Additionally, the code is super simple to write and understand. Have a look at the example below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

For further analysis [Read Here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

Please Vote if this answer help.

Comment: Thanks. But where should I place this in the code. Can you please help me?

Comment: What you need to do is assign an ID to the table in modal. then visit provided link in answer, you will find some CDN links which are necessary for datatables to export data. place them in global footer.php. Place provided code in you global javascript file OR in the same php page where the modal is added.

Comment: Hi Asad, I just tried your approach with a sample below. Can you see this please

Comment: can you please share the link @user11740857

Comment: Just added  above. Heading as "Jquery Datatables"

Comment: hey @user11740857! your program doesn't work as it is missing some libraries. I have set a Codepen [Link](https://codepen.io/asadk6103/pen/Vwpowgq) here. Please refer here.